# Convert List<dynamic> to List using LINQ

Tags: c#, linq, list, dynamic, collections

I'm having a collection `List<dynamic> dList`. In that, it has `string` items and `List<string>` items. Now I need to organize all the values in a single List.

Just refer the `List<dynamic>` dList

**Case: 1**

```
List<dynamic> dList = new List<dynamic>()
{
    "Selva",
    new List<string>() {"Bala"},
    new List<string>() {"Prayag", "Raj"},
    "Pavithran"
};
```

**Case: 2**

```
List<object> bala = new List<dynamic>()
{
    "Selva",
    new List<object>() {"Bala"},
    new List<object>() {"Prayag", "Raj"},
    "Pavithran"
};
```

The Output of the above two List are

[image]

My Expected Output is

[image]

How could I achieve the expected result from the above `List<dynamic>`? The List is generated at run time and I cannot to change the structure.

This is a small part of a complex Linq query, so, I need to achieve this in Linq.

Comment: Why do you have to use Linq to achieve your goal?

Comment: This is a small partition inside a Complex Linq Query in my main project. So, I need to achieve this in LINQ. Otherwise we can achieve using foreach loop and other basic syntax...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If order is important then you can convert every element to a `List<string>` and then flatten these:

```
List<dynamic> dList = new List<dynamic>()
{
    "Selva",
    new List<string>() {"Bala"},
    new List<string>() {"Prayag", "Raj"},
    "Pavithran"
};

var flattenedList = dList.SelectMany(d => 
{
    if (d is string) 
    {
        return new List<string>() { d };
    }
    else if (d is List<string>)
    {
        return (d as List<string>);
    }
    else 
    {
        throw new Exception("Type not recognised");
    }
});
```

Or, as a sexy one-liner with no type-checking (so...use at your own risk!)

```
dList.SelectMany(d => d as List<string> ?? new List<string>() { d })
```

Or, finally, in LINQ syntax:

```
var newList = 
    (from d in dList
    from d2 in EnsureListOfString((object)d)
    select d2
    );

public List<string> EnsureListOfString(object arg) 
{
    List<string> rtn = arg as List<string>;

    if (rtn == null) 
    {
        if (arg is string)
        {
            rtn = new List<string>() { arg as string };
        }
        else 
        {
            throw new Exception("Type not recognised.");
        }
    }

    return rtn;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your contribution. Now I edited the Question with one more case... Kindly assist me, how can I achieve in Case: 2 data

Comment: @IRPunch It should be the same (except changing the relevant casts from `string` to `object` and `List<string>` to `List<object>`). Are you having a particular difficulty?

Answer (score 1):

If the order of the elements is not important, you can do this:

```
dList.OfType<string>().Concat(dList.OfType<List<string>>().SelectMany(l => l));
```

This first selects all `string` elements from the list, then selects all `List<string>` elements and flattens them using `SelectMany` and finally concats all strings.